# HP Probook: BootDevice Not Found (3F0) after automatic BIOS update

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hp-laptop

On a brand new HP Probook laptop, after restarting Windows 10 the HP BIOS started to update automatically.

After the update Windows 10 doesn't start anymore. I always get stuck on the following screen:

```
BootDevice Not Found
Please install an operating system on your hard disk.
Hard Disk (3F0)
F2 System Diagnostics
For more information, please visit : www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup
```

I tried to:

1. Enable/Disable Secure Boot and Legacy Boot
2. Run diagnostics
3. Update HP BIOS via LAN from the BIOS itself
4. Boot from a Windows 10 USB stick:

   - Fix startup disk
   - Uninstall latest windows updates
   - Restore to a previous snapshot

Nothing from the above helps.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fixed the problem this way:

1) Booted from a Windows 10 USB stick (I created it using the Windows 10 Media Creation tool downloaded from microsoft.com)

2) Clicked "Repair your PC"

3) Opened "Command prompt"

`diskpart`
  — started the diskpart utility

`sel disk 0`
  — select this drive if you have one hard drive in your laptop

`list vol`
  — see the volumes on your computer

`sel vol #`
  — instead of # put the number of the volume which is called SYSTEM and has a FAT32 filesystem

`assign letter=Y:`
  — mount it as a drive — **IMPORTANT** - pick a drive letter that is free - in my case it was Y:

`exit`
  — exit diskpart

`dir y:\`
  — inspect that this drive does not contain any of your important data! - this is a double-check in case you would have chosen a drive letter (e.g. Y:) that would have been already occupied

`format Y: /FS:FAT32`
  — this is going to format the boot volume

`bcdboot C:\Windows /s Y: /f UEFI`
  — this will fix the boot volume

`exit`
  — remove the USB stick and restart your PC

Source: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-bootrec-fixboot-access-is-denied-error-on-windows-10